# What is the closure of a left-recursive LR(0) item with epsilon transitions?

Tags: parsing, language-agnostic, grammar, lr-grammar, epsilon

Let's say I have this grammar:

```
A: ε
 | B 'a'
B: ε
 | B 'b'
```

What is considered to be the closure of the item `A: • B 'a'`?
In other words, how do I deal with the epsilon transitions when figuring out closures?

Comment: Similar question for an LR(1) parser: [LR1 Parser and Epsilon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486920/lr1-parser-and-epsilon)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward.   Included in the closure of

```
    A = ... <dot> X ... ;
```

are all the rules

```
    X =   <dot> R1 R2 R3 ... ;
```

where first(R1) is not empty.  For each (nonempty) token K in first(R1), you'll need to (transitively!) include

```
    R1 = <dot> k ... ;
```

etc. but presumably you are already clear on this.

You specific question is what happens if R1 can be empty?  Then you also
need to include

```
    X =   R1 <dot> R2 ... ;
```

Similarly for R2 being empty, if R1 can be empty, and similarly for Ri being empty if R1 .. Ri-1 can be empty. In extreme circumstances, all the Ri can be empty (lots of optional subclauses in your grammar), and you can end up including

```
    X =  R1 R2 ... Rn <dot> ;
```

Note that determining that first(R1) "can be empty" is itself a transitive closure question.

The GLR parser generator that I built for DMS precomputes  first_can_be_empty using Warshall's algorithm and then uses that in the closure construction.

Comment: Huh, interesting... to clarify, by "Warshall" do you mean Floyd-Warshall? i.e. the all-pairs shortest paths algorithm?

Comment: Yes, but you don't need the "shortest" path, just the "existence" of a path, so you can do the whole thing with bits, and then you realize you can do it with bit vectors for a pretty significant speedup.